# Can't insert form data into database

Tags: php, mysql

**Answered**
Well this is interesting. Basically it didn't have to do with what I thought it did. it turns out that the id field on my database was screwed up in some way and it was attempting to enter a second number 0 primary key every time I tried to insert a new row. So I deleted the id column and recreated it making sure to mark it as auto-incrementing and also not entering any data there-in so that it could auto-increment without interruption. Now it seems to be working just fine *facepalm*

thanks to everyone that gave it a whack though!

**UPDATED**
So the issue with the notice is taken care of. The problem right now is that I'm still stuck with a blank white screen and I have no information actually getting into my database. I have no errors that I can see or think of but it's just not inserting anything into the database. Everyone has told me that I should move do POD or something but I don't have time to start from scratch. if anyone can think of anything that might be causing the white screen after the myriad of changes I've already made I will wet myself XD

I've updated my code to what I have currently running. Any ideas? I'm at the end of my rope T.T

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$hostname = "myHostName";
$username = "PreRegCustomers";
$dbname = "PreRegCustomers";
$password = "myPassword";
$usertable = "CustomerInfo";

//connect to mysql
$link_id = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link_id) {
    die("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later. error:".mysql_errno());
}
//make sure DB exists
if (!mysql_select_db($dbname)) die ("Connected to mysql but could not connect to the DB. error:".mysql_errno());

//avoid sql_injection
$firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
$streetAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['streetAddress']);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$badgeName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['badgeName']);

//write the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable 
    (firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, badgeName) 
    VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$streetAddress', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$country', '$email', '$phone', '$badgeName')";

//execute the query
mysql_query($sql); 
?>
```

Original Post:

---

So I'm pretty new to php. Like 2 days now and I'm trying to get my web form to insert data into a MySQL database hosted with go daddy. I've tried a bunch of different things, I know php is enabled and working, I have a DNS, I'd been getting the white screen of death but after some changes to my code I'm just getting a notice that says:

> Notice: Undefined index: country in /home/content/85/11323785/html/devTest/insert2.php on line 26

Now as far as I know, I should be able to ignore a notice except that it's still not inserting anything into my database. I just get a blank white screen with my `.php` file in the address bar and one notice.

Any help would be stellar! My code is as follows.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$hostname = "myHostName";
$username = "PreRegCustomers";
$dbname = "PreRegCustomers";
$password = "myPassword";
$usertable = "CustomerInfo";

//connect to mysql
$link_id = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link_id) {
    die("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later. error:".mysql_errno());
}
//make sure DB exists
if (!mysql_select_db($dbname)) die ("Connected to mysql but could not connect to the DB. error:".mysql_errno());

//avoid sql_injection
$firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
$streetAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['streetAddress']);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$badgeName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['badgeName']);

//write the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable 
    (firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, badgeName) 
    VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$streetAddress', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$country', '$email', '$phone', '$badgeName')";

//execute the query
mysql_query($sql); 
?>
```

Comment: First: Don't use the `mysql_` functions in new code! It's deprecated, use `mysqli_` or PDO instead. Prepared statements (a thing you should have a look at) also relieves you of the pain of sanitizing each variable you want to use in a query.

Comment: It means `$_POST['country']` is empty. i.e it is not being sent from the FORM. Check that your HTML FORM has `<input type="text" name="country">` or `<select name="country">` or whatever you used.

Comment: Database errors don't alert you. For mysql_*, you have to use mysql_error() right after mysql_query() to find out what the database errors are. But you should really use mysqli instead. It's not hard.

Comment: So when you guys are saying "use mysqli_" I get that is mysql Improved, but does that involve rewriting everything? or is it just literally replacing the bits that say "mysql_" with "mysqli_"?

Comment: So good call on the missing field... I hadn't realized I didn't have a country field. so that takes care of the one problem... however now I'm back to having just a big blank white screen with no information inserted into my database. driving me nuts XD

Comment: Yes, it's mostly a search and replace. but `mysqli` is not much better.

Comment: -1 for repeating the exact same question twice.

Answer (score 2):

First off, kuddo's the sanitizing your input.
It's better to use PDO, because it makes it easier to do the right thing.

**Check for missing input**
You can check whether a value is set using the `isset()` function.

```
if !(isset($_POST['country'])){ inform user about missing input
```

Alternatively if you don't mind the null value for `$country`, you can turn off the warning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

**The real error is elsewhere**
Note that the message just warns you that `$country` contains a `null` value.
If your DB is ok with that the insert should still happen, however it is more than likely that the country column is defined as `NOT NULL` and thus will not accept a null input.
You should make sure that all required fields are filed, or fill them yourself if there's a proper default value.

Note that you can also set a default value in the database definition.

**Tip: use PDO**
Using pdo your query would look something like:

```
//No escaping needed with PDO.
$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable 
(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, badgeName) 
VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :streetAddress, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :email, :phone, :badgeName)";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':firstName' => $firstName, 
                          ':lastName' => $lastName,
                          ':streetAddress' => $streetAddress,
                          ':city' => $city, 
                          ':state' => $state,
                          ':zip' => $zip,
                          ':country' => $country,
                          ':email' => $email,
                          ':phone' => $phone,
                          ':badgeName' => $badgeName));
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
For more details.

**Whitescreen issues**
There are no whitescreen issues, you are not telling php to display anything, so it does not display.

You end your segment with:

```
//execute the query
mysql_query($sql);  <<-- this command does not generate output.
```

So if you want output, you need to put something there e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);   
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error());
} else {
  echo('Success, row has been inserted');
}
```

Comment: well if successful it should insert the forms information into my database and then my form will redirect the page to the receipt.html page. but none of that happens. instead I have a blank page with the url of the .php file in it and no information gets inserted into the database. am I missing something on how this is supposed to work? I have a form mailer that works exactly this way but it works. I don't care about the page I just want the info in the database which is not happening.

Comment: Yes, you keep saying that, all your questions have already been answered, see: `$result = mysql_query($sql);   
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error());
} else {
  echo('Success, row has been inserted');
}` Lookup the error code in **google** and fix the problem. What is difficult?